# Issue in separating count for each product Angular4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, binding

I'm developing a shopping App with list items and cart items
I made a variable called increment which counts 1 every click on the add button

The first issue is i'm looping through an array from an API and i need to be able to make each item has it's own increment variable in order to count all in the cart item
Because when i click on plus icon, every item counts, i need to separate them

Second issue, how to show total items count inside the child component?
Because i tried to show it with static value in the child component via local variable and it didn't bind.

My HTML of the parent:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <app-cart #total>
     total items are:   {{total}}       
    </app-cart>
  </div>
  <ul *ngIf="items">
    <li class="padding-add" *ngFor="let item of items; let i of index">
      <div class=" col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 padding-add">
          <img src="{{item.imageUrl}}" width="200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padding-add">
          <h4>{{item.id}}- {{item.name}}</h4>
          <h6>Material: {{item.service1}}</h6>
          <h6>Options: {{item.service2}}</h6>
          <h6>Price: {{item.service3}} $</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
          <button (click)="addToCart()" class="btn-6 fa fa-plus"></button>
          <span>{{increment}}</span>
    <button (click)="removeFromCart()" class="fa fa-minus btn-6"></button>
  </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Parent TS:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
private getItemsService: JustCleanServiceService,
private spinner: NgxSpinnerService
) { }
items:any = {};
increment: number = 0;
total: number = 8;  
ngOnInit() {
this.getItems();
}
getItems() {
this.spinner.show() 
this.getItemsService.getItems().subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res)
    if (res) {
      this.items = res;
      this.spinner.hide();          
    }
  }
)
}
addToCart() {
this.increment++;
this.increment + this.total;
console.log(this.increment);
}
removeFromCart() {
this.increment--;
if(this.increment == -1) {
  this.increment++;
}
}
}
```

Child TS:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
total: number;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<p>total items are:    {{total}}</p>
```

Kindly assist me with both of the issues i'm facing

API link:
http://5a12745f748faa001280a746.mockapi.io/v1/stores/item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second issue, Use @Input Decorative to bind variables. Read about it here ->

https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Your first issue isn't very clear to me, but addToCart() looks ambiguous. Here, you are adding total and increment but not assigning it anywhere, why? Maybe, your problem lies in this line, or it may be intentional.

Comment: I will try the input, the first issue, i will give you example, its because i put the increment count inside the loop, so when i press on the add button on a product, all products are incrementing by one, so i need to count each one, did you get it?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Didn't get on my laptop yet, will try it in two hours and update you